# Is there a way to use a loop inside the tidyverse ecosystem?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse

I have tried looping through the mutate and fct_recode functions to recode this problem but did not succeed. Is there a way around it be it in tidyverse or any other way? Sorry for verbosity-I wanted to be as clear as possible.

```
set.seed(2021)

df <- tibble(

  a1 = factor(ifelse(sign(rnorm(30))==-1, 0, 1), labels = c("", "Yes")),
  a2 = factor(ifelse(sign(rnorm(30))==-1, 0, 1), labels = c("", "Yes")),
  b1 = factor(ifelse(sign(rnorm(30))==-1, 0, 1), labels = c("", "Yes")),
  b2 = factor(ifelse(sign(rnorm(30))==-1, 0, 1), labels = c("", "Yes")),
  d1 = gl(2, 15, labels = c("Males", "Females")),
  d2 = factor(ifelse(sign(rnorm(30))==-1, 0, 1), labels = c("Python", "R"))
)

df %>% count(a1)

# Replace "" with No

myvars <- c("a1", "a2", "b1", "b2")


df %>% mutate(a1 = factor(if_else(a1 == "", "No",
                                  as.character(a1))),
              a2 = factor(if_else(a1 == "", "No",
                                as.character(a1))),
              b1= factor(if_else(b1== "", "No",
                                  as.character(b1))))

#---- Attempt one (forloop)

# Desire for all the variables

for (i in myvars){

  df <- df %>%
    mutate(i = factor(if_else(i == "", "No",
                              as.character(i))))
}

df %>% count(a1) # No replacement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidyverse` has its own functions for "looping".

To apply a function for multiple columns you can use `across`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(across(all_of(myvars), 
               ~factor(if_else(. == "", "No", as.character(.)))))

df %>% count(a1)

#  a1        n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 No       12
#2 Yes      18
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (myvars) := lapply(.SD, function(x) factor(fifelse(x == "", "No",
             as.character(x))), .SDcols = myvars]
```

---

In the OP's `for` loop we need

```
for (i in myvars){

df <- df %>%
    mutate(!! i := factor(if_else(!! rlang::sym(i) == "", "No",
                          as.character(!! rlang::sym(i)))))
  } 

df %>% 
    count(a1)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  a1        n
#* <fct> <int>
#1 No       12
#2 Yes      18
```

---

Or we can use `fct_recode`

```
library(forcats)
df %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(myvars), ~ fct_recode(., No = '')))
```